# Entity Framework 6 Load List on Eager Load

Tags: .net, entity-framework, orm, entity-framework-6, one-to-many

Entity Framework is loading everything in the `Polygon` but my list of `LineSegments`. What am I missing?

Polygon:

```
public class Polygon
{
    List<LineSegment> _lineSegments = new List<LineSegment>();
    public List<LineSegment> LineSegments
    {
        get { return _lineSegments; }
        protected set { _lineSegments = value; }
    }

    public Point BasePoint { get; protected set; }

    public Vector NormalVector { get; protected set; }

    public int? DatabaseId { get; set; }

    // ...
}
```

LineSegment class (`Polygon` has a list of these)

```
public class LineSegment
{
    public virtual Distance Magnitude
    {
        get { return _magnitude; }
        set { _magnitude = value; }
    }
    private Distance _magnitude;

    public virtual Point BasePoint
    {
        get { return _basePoint; }
        set { this._basePoint = value; }
    }
    private Point _basePoint;

    public virtual Direction Direction
    {
        get { return _direction; }
        set { _direction = value; }
    }
    private Direction _direction;

    public int? DatabaseId { get; set; }

    // ...
}
```

And here is the relationship setup in the model:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Polygon>()
        .HasMany(polygon => polygon.LineSegments);
```

So there is a table for both Polygons and LineSegments, and they insert properly where the LineSegment has a reference to a Polygon. But when I try to retrieve them using eager loading, it doesn't load the list. I have the properties of LineSegment listed in the includes, but it's not working. I think I need to amend the relationship setup in the model, but I'm not sure how. **How can I correct this so that I load the list of LineSegments eagerly when I load a Polygon?** Here's the querying:

```
    private static List<Expression<Func<Polygon, object>>> polygonRegionNaviationProperties = new List<Expression<Func<Polygon, object>>>()
    {
        (polygon => polygon.BasePoint),
        (polygon => polygon.BasePoint.X),
        (polygon => polygon.BasePoint.Y),
        (polygon => polygon.BasePoint.Z),
        (polygon => polygon.NormalVector),
        (polygon => polygon.NormalVector.Direction),
        (polygon => polygon.NormalVector.Direction.Phi),
        (polygon => polygon.NormalVector.Direction.Theta),
        (polygon => polygon.NormalVector.Magnitude),
        (polygon => polygon.NormalVector.BasePoint.X),
        (polygon => polygon.NormalVector.BasePoint.Y),
        (polygon => polygon.NormalVector.BasePoint.Z),
        (polygon => polygon.LineSegments),
        (polygon => polygon.LineSegments.Select(lineSegment => lineSegment.Direction)),
        (polygon => polygon.LineSegments.Select(lineSegment => lineSegment.Direction.Phi)),
        (polygon => polygon.LineSegments.Select(lineSegment => lineSegment.Direction.Theta)),
        (polygon => polygon.LineSegments.Select(lineSegment => lineSegment.Magnitude)),
        (polygon => polygon.LineSegments.Select(lineSegment => lineSegment.BasePoint.X)),
        (polygon => polygon.LineSegments.Select(lineSegment => lineSegment.BasePoint.Y)),
        (polygon => polygon.LineSegments.Select(lineSegment => lineSegment.BasePoint.Z))
    };

    public Polygon GetPolygon(int? databaseId)
    {
        if(databaseId != null)
        {
            Polygon retrievedPolygon = Query((polygon => polygon.DatabaseId == databaseId), polygonRegionNaviationProperties);
            return retrievedPolygon;
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public override Polygon Query(Expression<Func<Polygon, bool>> match, List<Expression<Func<Polygon, object>>> includes = null)
    {
        using (var databaseContext = new ClearspanDatabaseContext())
        {
            databaseContext.Database.Log = Console.Write;

            if (includes != null)
            {
                var dataSet = databaseContext.Set<Polygon>(); // Get the relevant DataSet
                Polygon retrievedObject = includes.Aggregate( // Eagerly load the passed navigation properties
                        dataSet.AsQueryable(),
                        (current, include) => current.Include(include)
                    ).SingleOrDefault(match);
                databaseContext.Entry(retrievedObject).Collection(polygon => polygon.LineSegments).Load();
                return retrievedObject;
            }
            else
            {
                Polygon retrievedObject = databaseContext.Set<Polygon>().SingleOrDefault(match);
                databaseContext.Entry(retrievedObject).Collection(polygon => polygon.LineSegments).Load();
                return retrievedObject;
            }
        }
    }
```

**UPDATE**

Here is a link to a thinned out [project](https://bitbucket.org/Clearspan/testlibrary) illustrating my problem.

1. Clone it down.
2. Initialize the submodules (`git submodule init` and `git submodule update` in the root of the project) (this may happen automatically if you use SourceTree)
3. Run the PostgreSQL script, noting that you can't run it all at once since it's creating a database. Follow the comments at the top.
4. Run the unit tests, and note that they all should pass except InsertAndRetrievePolygon. That's because the List isn't retrieved, which you can see by hovering over the variables in the debugger.

Hopefully this is helpful to understanding, diagnosing, and solving this problem. You'll note that in my question I simplified the hierarchy that actually exists in the GeometryClassLibrary. Thanks, Scott H

Comment: You have to include only the navigation properties

Comment: At a first look everything seems to be fine. Are you sure that in DB there are `LineSegment`s related to `Polygon`? Also, why do you have this line: `databaseContext.Entry(retrievedObject).Collection(polygon => polygon.LineSegments).Load()` if you have already mentioned this navigation property in `includes`?

Comment: What happens in `LineSegment`'s constructor?

Comment: @ieaglle 1) Yes, the Lines table (TPH including LineSegments) has a column Polygon_DatabaseID. 2) Yeah that was a leftover from trying different things to try to make it work.

Comment: @GertArnold LineSegment has a null constructor for EF to use.

Comment: And nothing happening there? (Actually, I don't know what you mean by *null constructor*)

Comment: That's correct. There are implicit calls to parent constructors which are also empty/nothing happening.

Comment: Can you share a VS solution containing the code in which the issue occurs? I don't see anything that could explain this. The only thing I know could cause this is initializing a `Polygon` in `LineSegment`, but `LineSegment` doesn't even have this navigation property (and doesn't need it).

Comment: @GertArnold Check out the updated question. I added a self contained project exemplifying the problem. Please contact me with any questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the code of `Polygon.LineSegments`:

```
public virtual List<LineSegment> LineSegments
{
    get { return this._Edges.Select(e => (LineSegment)e).ToList(); }
    set { _Edges = value.ToList<IEdge>(); }
}
```

When EF populates a child collection it won't assign a *complete* collection to it, but initialize it if necessary and then add items to it. Now here's the pitfall: to which collection does EF add items? Not `_Edges`, but a transient collection that is build by `ToList()` each time `LineSegments` is addressed. *`_Edges` itself remains empty.*

Unfortunately, you can't solve this by `Include()`-ing `Edges` in stead of `LineSegments`, because this is the code of `Edges`:

```
protected List<IEdge> _Edges = new List<IEdge>();
public virtual List<IEdge> Edges
{
    get { return _Edges; }
    set { _Edges = value; }
}
```

And EF doesn't support interfaces. Frankly, I don't know if there is a decent work-around. This indirection in `LineSegments` is likely to cause more issues with EF. For instance, I don't think *relationship fixup* (auto-population of navigation properties from entities loaded into the context) will run either.

I understand these classes are from an external library. I see all these `XyzEntityFramework` partial classes there (e.g. `LineSegmentEntityFramework`) that seem to add properties to facilitate working with EF. Maybe they are willing to look at your issue and find a solution for it.

Comment: Thanks, this is very informative. We actually own those external libraries as well, and I set up those partial classes with EF properties. Judging by your comment about interfaces and EF though, it looks like for compatibility we would have to change that to not use an interface. I'll look into this tomorrow morning (UTC - 5). Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change your class as follow:

```
public class Polygon
{
    public virtual List<LineSegment> LineSegments
    {
        get;
        set;
    }


    // ...
}
```

In your query, include only navigation properties. Strings, primitive types and enumeration types shouldn't be included. Like this:

```
var dataSet = databaseContext.Set<Polygon>();
Polygon retrievedObject = dataSet.Include(i => i.LineSegments).SingleOrDefault(match);

return retrievedObject;
```

Does that work for you?

Comment: Unfortunately no. And actually all of those eagerly loaded properties are navigation properties, not primitives. We wrap a lot of types that seem like they would be primitives. Does my Fluent API mapping look correct?

Answer (score 0):

I'd take a look at the first example about one-to-many relationships in Code First here. 
http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx

I think Fabio Luz was on the right track. The LineSegments collection should be virtual. You can also try overriding the default constructor and instantiate the property. In addition, there should probably be a virtual property for the Polygon in the LineSegments class to complete the referential relation.

```
public class Polygon 
{
    public Polygon()
    {
        LineSegments = new List<LineSegment>();
    }

    public virtual List<LineSegment> LineSegments
    {
        get;
        set;
    }


    // ...
}

public class LineSegment
{
   public virtual Polygon Polygon { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, tried those things just now, but unfortunately to no avail. Did you have a chance to clone down the code and give it a try?